# How to parse log-file, containing uncertain pattern of data?

Tags: python, regex

For a successful request, log file has been written as below

```
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
```

Line beginning with `o` and has `some data` (as shown above) and ends with another line beginning with `o`. This is the pattern.

If there are multiple such requests, log file keeps on appending as shown below

```
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
```

There might be some wrong generated data in the file, that can be for any earlier requests or latest requests.

**If wrong-data generated is not for latest request, can be ignored.**

Example :

```
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
# Should be indication of request i.e., line beginning with o, followed some data
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
```

**If wrong-data generated is for latest request, it should be caught and highlighted.**

Example :

```
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673   
# No line present i,e., (o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd)
```

Missing line can be first line beginning with `o` or last line beginning with `o`

I need to check, for every request logs are written in this format and how many successful and un-successful requests are captured in a file ?

Approach 1: can read the file contents and then parse as if line beigns with o etc, which i don't feel feasible

Approach 2 : I feel, reg-ex is optimum and best solution.

Which would be best ? and could you please help me to achieve it ?

**Tried so far:**

```
reg_ex1 = "o\s+\d+(\.\d+)?\d+\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+-"
reg_ex2 = "o\s+\d+(\.\d+)?\d+\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
with open(""some_file.log, 'r') as content_file:
content = content_file.read()
pattern1 = re.compile(reg_ex1)
begin_lines = len(pattern1.findall(content))
pattern2 = re.compile(reg_ex2)
end_lines = len(pattern2.findall(content))
if begin_lines == end_lines:
   print "File has successful requests captured"
else:
   print "File has un-successful requests captured"
   # If wrong-data generated is not for latest request, can be ignored.
   # If wrong-data generated is for latest request, it should be caught and highlighted.

May be not a good idea though, please let me know.
```

**UPD**:

```
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 001-
n A-123456===123 1452830400 1 14521
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231541
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573==123 1452830400 1 926731
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 002-
n A-123456===456 1452830400 1 14522
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231542
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37452
n G-809573===456 1452830400 1 926732
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 003-
n A-123456===789 1452830400 1 14523
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231543
n B-967845 1452830400 1  374513
n G-809573===789 1452830400 1 926733
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
```

For the above text, I would want to extract Packet 1 and 3.

Comment: This is what you want, now where is what you've tried?

Comment: @DirtyBit thanks for pointing it, added. Please check.

Comment: Is the number of lines for a successful request always the same? Like in the first example you provided there are 6 lines (including both o lines), can this vary?

Comment: @StackGuru you are complicating things, I would opt for check the first and the last line being strating from `o` otherwise its a bad file.

Comment: @DirtyBit Ok, how to capture the number of successful/un-successful requests ? For the first request if it failed to print last line beginning with o and for the last request if it failed to print first line beginning with o. Would you say it as good file ?

Comment: @StackGuru Posted an answer for it, Pardon me, but what responses do you intend to get?

Answer (score 2):

To check if the file is `good` or `bad`, We'd play with the first and last line of the file, Considering;

1. The file is bad if the first line does not start with `o`
2. The file is bad if the last line does not end with `o`
3. The file is good if the first and the last line starts with `o`

list.txt:

```
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673
# Should be indication of request i.e., line beginning with o, followed some data
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -
n A-123456 1452830400 1 1452
n C-73652 1452830400 1 23154
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 92673
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfd
```

**Hence**:

```
logFile = "list.txt"    
with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

for line in content:
    if line.startswith("o"):  # check if the first line starts with o
        if str(content[-1]).strip("[']").split()[0] == 'o': # check if last line starts with o
            print("File is good.")
        else:
            print("File is bad.")
        break
    else:                    # end if the first line does not start with o
        print("File is bad.")
        break
```

**EDIT**:

To get all the responses between **valid** pair of `o`'s:

list.txt:

```
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 001-
n A-123456 1452830400 1 14521
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231541
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 926731
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 002-
n A-123456 1452830400 1 14522
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231542
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37452
n G-809573 1452830400 1 926732
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd
o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 003-
n A-123456 1452830400 1 14523
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231543
n B-967845 1452830400 1  374513
n G-809573 1452830400 1 926733
```

**Hence**:

```
import re
def GetTheResponses(infile):
     with open(infile) as fp:
         red = fp.read()
         for result in re.findall('o (.*?)o ', red, re.S):
             print(result)

GetTheResponses('list.txt')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 001-
n A-123456 1452830400 1 14521
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231541
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 926731

123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 002-
n A-123456 1452830400 1 14522
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231542
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37452
n G-809573 1452830400 1 926732
```

**EDIT 2**: (for better readability):

```
count = 1
for result in re.findall('o (.*?)o ', red, re.S):
    print("Response Packet: {}".format(count))
    print("\n".join(result.split("\n")[1:]))
    count +=1
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Response Packet: 1
n A-123456 1452830400 1 14521
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231541
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37451
n G-809573 1452830400 1 926731

Response Packet: 2
n A-123456 1452830400 1 14522
n C-73652 1452830400 1 231542
n B-967845 1452830400 1  37452
n G-809573 1452830400 1 926732
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong. This file contains response for may requests. For each request, data is written in this format : Line beginning with o and has some data (as shown above) and ends with another line beginning with o.

Comment: basically, it's validating against all such responses occurred in that file.

Comment: @StackGuru Do you want the responses in a list or just a print would do?

Comment: Print should be fine.

Comment: @StackGuru needed a little fix in the edit, it should work fine as your intention now! :)

Comment: nope. Have edited your answer and posted a scenario, where i'm not getting desired response.

Comment: @StackGuru Please do not edit my answer like that, a better approach is always to edit your original question to add such. PS. What makes you think Packet 2 is unsuccessful? Clearly that should give you Packet 1 and 2.

Comment: sorry. sure, thanks for mentioning it. If you look at the sample response for a successful request, starts with "o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 -" and ends with "o 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 3 30 10 some_random_text_alphanumeric_jdjfdjfdfhdkjfhdkhfdhfdfdfhkdhfkdjfdkjfkdfdkfdkjnc maxbgrsdfuyhlwkjdnkshbvhsgdvsdsjdbskdhskdjoihe73njndedejdoekekdednd"

Comment: @StackGuru You are twisting your original question. The goal here would be to extract each chunk between the `o`'s. And in this sample there are 2 chunks. 1st from `o` to `o` and second from the later coming `o` to the next `o`. And the last one does not have a starting `o`.

Comment: Please go through the question again and even mentioned to fetch number if successful n un-successful request. I posted a sample logs for successful request as well.

Comment: Hope I'm not confusing :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190430/discussion-between-dirtybit-and-stackguru).

Comment: any updates ? Tried to get in touch with you over chat

Comment: @StackGuru Left you a message there.

Answer (score 0):

I would definetely recomment Approach1, Why..?
in this way, we have flexibilty to read/iterate each line specifically..

```
with open('file.txt', r) as fp:
  line = fp.readline()
  print(type(line))  #string

  #do anything with line(string)
  #1. split_list= fp.split() -- list of values separated by space
  #2. Check type of each element: 
   # split_list[0].isalpha(), 
   # split_list[0].isalpha(),
   # split_list[0].isdigit(),
   # split_list[0].isspace() like so, and then do required adding to final dict/list..
```

Make sure to try: catch, every step.. as log files are unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

```
^n\s.+[\n\r]+o\s.+[\n\r]+n\s.+|^n\s.+[\n\r]+n\s.+[\n\r]+n\s.+[\n\r]+n\s.+[\n\r]+(?!o)|^o\s.+[\n\r]+o\s.+[\n\r]+o\s.+
```

[image]